# Is there any hymn sung in praise of Rām Setu?

Tags: rama

There has been quite a lot of hymns in praise of natural objects like Gangā, Aruṇāçal, Kāśi, etc. due to their religious significances. I wonder if there has been any praise for Rām Setu also? If Rām Setu is the same setu/bridge build by the army of Rām, there has to be a hymn created by some traditional acharya at least, if not to found in scripture(s).

Comment: There’s Setu mahatmya in Skanda Purana. It more so talks of all the religious places at Rameswaram more than a hymn I guess, thought it describes glories of Setu. Nice Q btw.